# how to set a value default if no record found in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a query that return an array of weekly sums of records in a table.

the query look like this

```
with date_ranges (range_name, range_dates) as
              ( values ('week_0', tstzrange ((now()::date-interval '6 days'),  now(), '[]'))
                      , ('week_1', tstzrange ((now()::date-interval '13 days'), (now()::date-interval '6 days')))
                      , ('week_2', tstzrange ((now()::date-interval '20 days'), (now()::date-interval '13 days')))
                      , ('week_3', tstzrange ((now()::date-interval '27 days'), (now()::date-interval '20 days')))
              )
                select range_name, range_dates, sum("transactionTotal") total_amount 
        from "MoneyTransactions" mt
        join date_ranges dr on (mt."entryType" = 'sold' AND mt."createdAt" <@ range_dates)
        group by range_name, range_dates
        order by range_name;
```

It is working as expected except that if a week contains no record, the query doesn't return any thing just skips it.

My question is is it posible to return a default value like `0` instead.

this is the output of the query

```
[
        {
            "range_name": "week_0",
            "range_dates": [
                {
                    "value": "2020-09-03T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "inclusive": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "2020-09-09T18:16:42.328Z",
                    "inclusive": true
                }
            ],
            "total_amount": "294450"
        },
        {
            "range_name": "week_1",
            "range_dates": [
                {
                    "value": "2020-08-27T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "inclusive": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "2020-09-03T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "inclusive": false
                }
            ],
            "total_amount": "13800"
        },
        {
            "range_name": "week_2",
            "range_dates": [
                {
                    "value": "2020-08-20T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "inclusive": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "2020-08-27T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "inclusive": false
                }
            ],
            "total_amount": "55200"
        }
    ]
```

as you can see `week_3` is not there, I just want to make the `total_amount` = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`, which keeps the left hand record, even if no records are found in the right hand table...

```
with date_ranges (range_name, range_dates) as
              ( values ('week_0', tstzrange ((now()::date-interval '6 days'),  now(), '[]'))
                      , ('week_1', tstzrange ((now()::date-interval '13 days'), (now()::date-interval '6 days')))
                      , ('week_2', tstzrange ((now()::date-interval '20 days'), (now()::date-interval '13 days')))
                      , ('week_3', tstzrange ((now()::date-interval '27 days'), (now()::date-interval '20 days')))
              )
                select range_name, range_dates, sum("transactionTotal") total_amount 
        from
            date_ranges dr
        LEFT JOIN
            "MoneyTransactions" mt
                 on (mt."entryType" = 'sold' AND mt."createdAt" <@ range_dates)
        group by range_name, range_dates
        order by range_name;
```

Formatting altered only to make it clear what I changed.

You may also want to change `SUM()` to `COALESCE(SUM(), 0)` so as to replace any `NULL` (no amounts to sum up) with a `0`.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the coalesce function?

if that doesn't work for you, you can create a function to test the output.

sorry for my bad english

Comment: They need an OUTER join before they need to think about `COALESCE()`.  Coalesce will turn a `NULL` to `0`, but at present they don't even get a `NULL`.